# Running two single-node cassandra clusters using different ports

Tags: cassandra

I want to run two instances of cassandra on a single machine. It runs fine with two loopback addresses 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.0.1 as the `listen_address, rpc_address` with the same `native_port: 9042`. But i shall be using the two resultant single-node clusters from a different machine so i need to have the addresses which can be identified by the other machines(loopbacks and localhost out of question) of the network.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You first need to create 2 IP address for your machine. This can be done by

- Setting 2 NIC Cards (or)
- Assigning multiple IP for a single NIC.

This can be done by assigning static IP (Make sure you provide the proper gateway and subnet so it will be accessible by other machine) and assign IP addresses, below link explains how to assign multiple IP addresses along with the bottlenecks of doing so:

http://www.tomshardware.com/faq/id-1925787/computer-address.html

After you have created 2 IP addresses, start each Cassandra Server with different IP address.
Do a telnet test:

```
telnet <IP address> <port(9042)>
```

from any other machine to check your Cassandra server is started with the assigned IP address.