# Running multiple cassandra instances on one machine

Tags: cassandra

This is my second attempt at setting up a 3-node Cassandra cluster on my machine. I'm not able to start the first instance. 
During startup I get

```
Exception encountered during startup
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Invalid yaml: file:/home/user1/TestCluster/node1/dsc-cassandra-2.2.8/conf/cassandra.yaml
```

and alot of lines that I'm not able to make any sense of (I fail to see why the yaml is invalid).

My approach consisted of the following steps:

1. I unzipped a tarball installation into 3 folders (as i want 3 instances).
2. In each `cassandra.yaml`:

   - `cluster_name` was set
   - `seeds:` "127.0.0.2"  (same for all nodes)
   - `rpc_address, listen_address` were set to 127.0.0.2-4 for all nodes
   - `rpc_port` was set (9160, 9161, 9162)
   - `data_file_directories`,  `commitlog_directories`, `saved_caches_directory` were set for all
3. In each `cassandra-env.sh` the `JMX_PORT` was set (8081,8082,8083)

`etc/hosts` was edited so that 127.2-4 are aliases for 127.0.0.1

**My questions are:** What am I doing wrong? How can this be fixed? Is there any other simple way to do this on ubuntu?

I'm including the error incase it makes any sense. Will remove if it takes up too much space.

```
ERROR 12:19:12 Exception encountered during startup
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Invalid yaml: file:/home/user1/TestCluster/node1/dsc-cassandra-2.2.8/conf/cassandra.yaml
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.loadConfig(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:118) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.loadConfig(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:85) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.loadConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:135) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.<clinit>(DatabaseDescriptor.java:119) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:507) [apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:641) [apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.ConstructorException: null; Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:org.apache.cassandra.config.Config; exception=Cannot create property=data_file_directories for JavaBean=org.apache.cassandra.config.Config@24a35978; No single argument constructor found for class [Ljava.lang.String;;  in 'reader', line 10, column 1:
    cluster_name: 'Testcluster'
    ^
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructYamlObject.construct(Constructor.java:333) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObject(BaseConstructor.java:182) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructDocument(BaseConstructor.java:141) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getSingleData(BaseConstructor.java:127) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadFromReader(Yaml.java:481) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadAs(Yaml.java:475) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.loadConfig(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:111) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: Cannot create property=data_file_directories for JavaBean=org.apache.cassandra.config.Config@24a35978; No single argument constructor found for class [Ljava.lang.String;
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.constructJavaBean2ndStep(Constructor.java:299) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.construct(Constructor.java:189) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructYamlObject.construct(Constructor.java:331) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: No single argument constructor found for class [Ljava.lang.String;
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructScalar.construct(Constructor.java:379) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObject(BaseConstructor.java:182) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.constructJavaBean2ndStep(Constructor.java:296) ~[snakeyaml-1.11.jar:na]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

Comment: What is the Cassandra version you are using? You can't just define IP addresses 127.0.0.1-3, have you added it your hosts entry or some where to define where it should lookup when 127.0.0.1-3 is used? I assume you are accessing your Cassandra from your localhost itself.

Comment: @ShobanSundar I am using version 2.2. I thought those were loopback addresses (so i didnt have to 'do' anything, if that makes sense)? 
Have not defined the lookup nor added to hosts entry. Yes I am running Cassandra from my localhost. As you probably can tell: I am a beginner, so its quite possible I'm missing some steps.

Comment: This post might help you to run multiple instances of Cassandra in single host: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42644396/running-two-single-node-cassandra-clusters-using-different-ports/42647926#42647926

Comment: @ShobanSundar Threadstarter wants to reach  the nodes from a different machine (which is why he needs addresses that can be identified by other machines). So the problem and solution is to something else.  However, it seems like the first part of that post is what i want (i.e. running several instances on a single machine) and where i am experiencing problems.

Comment: @ShobanSundar I tried using aliases to the loopback interface now, but the same problem remains. Is this what you were thinking of?

Comment: Were you able to start successfully all the nodes? Check did you got any error in the startup log

Comment: @ShobanSundar Unable to start node 1 (127.0.0.1) . I dont know how to run the other instances when i only have one bin.. Connection is refused still. But found this in what i think is the startup log: 

ERROR 09:52:27 Exception encountered during startup
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Invalid yaml: file:/home/user1/test_cluster/dsc-cassandra-2.2.8/conf/cassandra.yaml...
and then it points to alot i dont understand at all.

Comment: To run multiple instances you need multiple bins, and secondly when you bind it to the 127.0.0.1-3 IP address, it might have problems in identifying seeds. So you can either run all instances in 127.0.0.1 IP address with different jmx, cql and rpc ports(but that won't be in cluster mode)

Answer (score 2):

I would just use CCM if this is strictly for testing purposes on local machine.

https://github.com/pcmanus/ccm

Comment: Yes CCM is my last resort, if doing it manually turns out to be impossible. In theory it should be 'simple' to do this on Ubuntu (according to various sources), so prefer to do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your cofiguration is correct, I Have done exactly what you describe and it works fine. 
Problem seems to be that you have some sort of error in `cassandra.yaml` file. Please check line:

```
data_file_directories:
    - /var/lib/cassandra/data
```

It works when it is like this (two lines), when you put it in one line it throws error from your post.